# How to retrieve data from mysql in html by calling a function?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, mysql

I'm trying to retrieve data from MySQL and place it in HTML by calling a function, the PHP conf works fine when open in the browser. But when trying to call, nothing happens. I can't understand what's wrong, tried google it for solutions, but nothing actually works.

here is my PHP code

```
<?php
include("conn.php");


// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
echo "Failed to connect: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
mysqli_select_db($con, "users");
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM drivers");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>id</th>
<th>First Name</th>
<th>Last Name</th>
<th>Email</th>
</tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['firstName'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['lastName'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

and here is my ajax calling

```
<script type="text/javascript" src = "jquery-3.5.1.min.js">
$(document).ready(function (){
  $("#show").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "connection.php",
      async: false,
      dataType: "html",
      success: function(response){
        $("#container").html(response);
      }
    });
  });
});</script>
```

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: Take some basic debugging steps: 1) Check the console of your browser, does it report any errors? 2) Check the Network tab in the browser and see if the AJAX call is even taking place. 3) `console.log` the `response` in your success handler, check what you receive.

Comment: As @El_Vanja mentions, you should perform some debugging. Press F12 in your browser to open the development tools. Find the tab called "Console". Here you should be able to find any errors in your javascript code. You can also add `console.log("your trace/debug texts");` at different places in your code to trace if the code is executed and/or if variables are set as expected. The `console.log()` will output to the console tab in your browser :)

Comment: scripts working fine when tested... When I call ajax in the console then working fine , but the click handler is not working. When I click the button that corresponding with the .click handler is not working and I can't see why ?

Comment: maybe put the js code in another script tag, not in the one where you actually request the jQuery.min ... also you are trying to get data, so send a GET request instead of a POST request... and also, do you have a `button` or a clickable element with a `id="show"` in your HTML?

Comment: @Argee Thanks mate, you were right. The issue was the script tag... now it's working fine .. appreciate it!

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src = "jquery-3.5.1.min.js"> may be space in src link

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
$("#show").click(function(){
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "connection.php",
  async: false,
  dataType: "html",
  success: function(response){
    $("#container").html(response);
  }
});});
```